# How to create an Animated Image WebM file with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, webm

How can I create an animated image WebM file (not a video file) using ffmpeg-python ? Here below I am using the ffmpeg with related arguments yet, this function below creates an video instead of an animated image :

```
ffmpeg.input(video_url, ss=0)
.filter('scale', motion_width, -1)
.filter('fps', fps=6, round='up')
.output(out_filesystem_motion_filename, pix_fmt='yuv420p', vframes=18, loop=0)
.overwrite_output()
.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I found out that I need to use "webp" instead of "webm" for the animated image. The final command for ffmpeg to create a webm from a video file from moment ss with 6 fps for about 3 seconds is :

```
ffmpeg.input(video_url, ss=0)
.filter('scale', motion_width, -1)
.filter('fps', fps=6, round='up')
.output(out_filesystem_motion_filename, vframes=18, loop=0)
.overwrite_output()
.run()
```